# How to draw a rectangle with variable vertical height after a line of text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a rectangle (or a framed box) in several pages after some blocks of text. The rectangle must span horizontally the whole `\linewidth` after the text and vertically until the end of the text area of that page. The height must also be dynamically adjusted for the free space depending on the amount of text before. I've tried doing it with the **tikz** package but, honestly, that's way beyond my tex knowledge.

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1]

% Draw rectangle here with linewidth and that spans vertically 
% until the end of the area text of this page

\newpage

\lipsum[2]

% Draw rectangle here with linewidth and that spans vertically 
% until the end of the area text of this page

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution with `tikz`

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\bfill}{%
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\fill[color = blue!30] (0, 0) rectangle (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1]

\bfill

\newpage
\lipsum[2]

\bfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use `tcolorbox` and its `height fill` option -- it will fill remaining text part of the page with a box of the given color.

The `\filltobottom` uses `\NewTotalTCBox` and some options and some empty content. The options `breakable,height fill` are crucial here, as well as `tcbox width=forced center,width=\linewidth` in order to force the box to use the linewidth (other than the 'actual' content)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[verbose,bmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\NewTotalTCBox{\filltobottom}{O{}}{breakable, enhanced,colback=yellow,sharp corners,height fill,tcbox width=forced center,width={\linewidth},#1}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1]

\filltobottom[colback=green]

\clearpage

\lipsum[2]

\filltobottom


\end{document}
```

[image]